# Sqlite basic queries

Tags: sqlite

I have a database called `movie.db`. I would like to know the schema of the database in a single SQL query. If possible I would also like to know the number of tables in the database. Could some one tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the table count from db use following query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';
```

and to access schema

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```